# no ethernet connection when installing debian

Tags: debian, ethernet, debian-installer

no ethernet connection when installing debian.

I am using debian net install.

I just need to connect to internet & i plugedin ethernet cable but its unable to connect.

I am inside installer so there is no proper terminal or sudo or ifconfig etc...

Comment: Most Linux installers, including Debian's, will provide a terminal with root privileges on another virtual console, accessible using a Control+Alt+function key combination. You might have to first answer the installer's questions about the language and keyboard layout to use, before the terminal access will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I have seen this, it is because the network card on the computer is either broken or unsupported. Is getting a second network card a possibility? Even many of the ones that connect to USB seem to work for the network installer.

Comment: I am on my laptop. So i think i need to get usb ethernet adopter because card can not be change i guess.